# Reference in the function doesn't change item outside of it. C++

Tags: c++, function, reference

Trying to get value out from the function via reference, but it seems that I keep getting value that was assigned before function call.

```
void third()
{
    int summ = mainInput(3);
    int second = 0;
    cout << "You should pay " << fiveBill(summ, second) << second;
}

int fiveBill(int summ,int &two)
{
    int five=0;
    if (summ%2==0)
    {
        two = summ / 2;
    }
    else
    {
        two = (summ - 5) / 2;
        five++;
    }
    while (two>4)
    {
        two -= 5;
        five += 2;
    }
    return five;
}
```

Variable "second" keeps showing as 0 as I call it, while I am sure it changes inside a function.

Comment: Are you sure that the value being assigned to `two` in the function isn't just `0`?

Comment: Aur you sure the mainInput call isn't returning something unexpected?

Comment: mainInput returns 7 most of the time so two should return 1, but never happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, the order of function call argument evaluation is intentionally unspecified. It is perfectly possible for the compiler to evaluate `second` as the argument to `<<` before it evaluates the call to `fiveBill(summ, second)`. Just call `fiveBill` in a separate prior expression, or split the output into two expressions.

Comment: Worked great
Thank you